# simulation error with dpi (c code from flex)

Tags: verilog, system

we are simulating the sv based vip using flex/bison for testcase generation.C code(from flex) Linked through DPI.The c code is compiled in modelsim with vlog -work lib tab.c -lfl -ly .
object file is generated. But no .so file .
The issue is when we simulate the code it gives the below error.

```
#  Error (suppressible): (vsim-3197) Load of "/tmp/usr@pc_dpi_6655/linuxpe_gcc-4.7.4/vsim_auto_compile.so" failed: /tmp/ramandeep@fpgaaltera_dpi_6655/linuxpe_gcc-4.7.4/vsim_auto_compile.so: undefined symbol: yywrap.
```

Please provide your valuable feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's hard to give advice without any code. Please can you supply an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Matthew Taylor The code won't help in this case. They have not defined yywrap() which you need when working with Lex/Flex. It is in the manual!

Answer (score 0):

You need pass your link commands to vsim, not vlog

```
vsim -ldflags "-lfl -ly" ...
```